# Jquery validate: How to validate that all or none of a group of textboxes have values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have a form consisting of a couple of dozen labels and textboxes. But for simplicity's sake, let's say I have only six such items:

```
<div class="price-row">
    <span>A-text</span>
    <input type="text" id="input-A" name="A" required>
</div>
<div class="price-row">
    <span>B-text</span>
    <input type="text" id="input-B" name="B" required>
</div>
<div class="price-row">
    <span>C-text</span>
    <input type="text" id="input-C" name="C" required>
</div>
<div class="price-row">
    <span>D-text</span>
    <input type="text" id="input-D" name="D" required>
</div>
<div class="price-row">
    <span>E-text</span>
    <input type="text" id="input-E" name="E" required>
</div>
<div class="price-row">
    <span>F-text</span>
    <input type="text" id="input-F" name="F" required>
</div>
```

And the rules are as follows:

If A has a value, then B must also have a value. And vice versa.
If C, D, E or F has a value, then every input has got to have a value.

A value here means "has text of length > 0". But in reality, I also check some validity (is it a number, is it a valid e-mail address, etc.)

I have tried to validate the first set of rules, the ones pertaining to A and B, but this does not work:

```
$("#myform").validate({
                rules: {
                    A: {
                        depends: function(element) {
                            ($("#input-A").val().length > 0) == ($("#input-B").val().length > 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

My thinking is that the above "depends" statement should make sure that the page only validates if the function called returns True. But I can submit the form even if one of the text areas has text and the other doesn't.

Why is this, and what should I do instead?

Answer (score 1):

Your code...

```
rules: {
    A: {
        depends: function(element) {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

There is no such thing as a `depends` rule.

[`depends` is a ***property*** that goes under an existing rule in order to *"apply the rule only in certain conditions"*](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#rules).

```
rules: {
    A: {
        required: {
            depends: function(element) {
                // return true or false here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever the `depends` function returns `true`, the associated `required` rule is activated.

That being said, the function/logic is flawed...

```
depends: function(element) {
    ($("#input-A").val().length > 0) == ($("#input-B").val().length > 0);
}
```

- You need a `return` statement.
- You can't use `($("#input-A").val().length > 0)` as part of the `depends` function under `required` for input `A` because it will always evaluate to `false`.  It always starts off empty, right?  *(Besides, it doesn't make sense to change the field's rule based upon the same field's own content... you'd probably never be able to satisfy this rule.)*

---

Try something more like this...

```
rules: {
    A: {
        required: {
            depends: function(element) {
                return $("#input-B").is(':filled');
            }
        }
    },
    B: {
        required: {
            depends: function(element) {
                return $("#input-A").is(':filled');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`depends` will return `true` if B is filled out and activate the `required` rule on `A`.  The same logic is applied to field `B`.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/t9y2x3jf/**

**NOTE**:  You ***must*** remove any inline HTML5 `required` attributes from your `input` elements, otherwise, these will over-ride your `depends` logic.

```
<input type="text" id="input-A" name="A" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I realize I was being very sloppy. But this was very informative. The fiddle does what I want. Now for me to understand why I can't get it to work in my project even if I have the function return false every time :) I actually didn't have required set for these inputs. It was a bad copy-paste on my part. Some of the other inputs, though, have required.

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson, naturally, I cannot even begin to explain your observations without seeing the code that reproduces your problem.  Check the obvious... console errors, jQuery & plugin versions, HTML, etc.  Also use [the `debug` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#debug) within `.validate()` to get more help.